# Best way of transferring songs that were recorded onto floppy disk using a Clavinova CVP-103

Tags: midi, digital-piano, computer

We have a Clavinova CVP-103 which my wife used to record a bunch of music onto floppy discs years ago. I'm trying to work out the best way of ensuring she can still listen to  her music without having to play it through the CVP-103, as we would ideally like to replace it with something lighter, less bulky and more up-to-date.

I have some experience with midi, and own FL Studio and a Scarlett 2i4. Importing the midi files from the floppy discs didn't really work because of the way the piano records the music all as one track. Although I could get it to play in FL Studio, none of the voices were set up and it seemed like it would be a complete nightmare to sort out.

The only thing I can think of that would be remotely practical at this point would be to record them directly from the piano into FL Studio as audio files using an external microphone, but we don't own one and I'd rather not have to purchase something that we're never going to need to use again.

Are there any other options I've not thought about that might work?

Comment: Recording audio would work much better by using a cable connected to any output of the piano (line out, headphone out?), rather than a microphone. Could you provide more details about the files and the tracks, e.g. do the contain multiple tracks played simultaneously with different instrument sounds? Anyway, the very first thing to do is to backup all the floppy discs to some more modern storage space (e.g. your computer), as floppy discs, especially old ones, may not be too reliable.

Comment: It should save a MIDI type 0 file; which is a single track containing all the channels with correct voice/reverb setup at the head of each channel. I've no experience with FL, but a fairly basic requirement of a sequencer is to be able to sensibly spit this data back out with the correct channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to record the audio, an audio connecting cable would be easier, cheaper and sound better than a microphone.

Or you could persist with deciphering the MIDI files.   If you find it hard to work with a Type 0 MIDI track (single track containing multiple channels) in FL Studio, there are other programs.   MuseScore will do it.  (Don't be put off by it being primarily a notation program.  And it's free.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about MuseScore. It made me look at Finale, which I have a copy of - that correctly splits the channels into separate staves, which makes the tracks much easier to work with